# Access a div in a var

Tags: jquery

I have 2 div in a var. How can I pick up just one of the div?
If I knew the parent I would use find. But I do not know the parent
Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/fLn9wccn/

JQUERY:

```
var resultat = "<div id='first'> first </div><div id='second'> second </div>"
// var resultat = $("#parent").find("#first")
$("#solution").html(resultat);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="first">first</div>
<div id="second">second</div>

<br><br><br>

<div id="solution"> solution </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `$.fn.filter` to filter the collection you've.

```
$("#solution").html($(resultat).filter('#first'));
```

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

[**Know more about it on jQuery DOCs**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the first div, I re-added the first bit to make up for the split removing what it split the string with.

```
$("#solution").html("<div " + resultat.split("<div ")[0]);
```